# Check bootstrap table row - Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox, html-table

I need to check/uncheck a table checkbox based on a value stored in a database. I'm not an experienced programmer. I've been Google-ing this for a whole day with no luck. Hope someone's going to help me.

Here's the code :

```
echo "<table data-toggle='table' data-click-to-select='true' id='potable'>";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th data-field='state' data-checkbox='true'></th>";
echo "<th data-field='code'>Code</th>";
echo "<th data-field='description'>Description</th>";
echo "<th data-field='verb'>Verb</th>";
echo "<th>Actions</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</thead>";
echo "<tbody>";
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    extract($row);
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>"; ?>
    <script>
        var select = <?php echo "{$selected}"; ?>;
        if (select == 1) {
// INSERT HERE JAVASCRIPT LINE THAT CHECKS THE CURRENT CHECKBOX
        else { 
//UNCHECK THE CURRENT CHECKBOX
        }
    </script>
    <?php
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>{$code}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$description}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$verb}</td>";
    echo "<a type='button' class='btn btn-primary left-margin' href='po-info.php?id={$id}'>Info</a>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";                                           
}
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: where is your checkbox?

Comment: It's here : echo "<th data-field='state' data-checkbox='true'></th>"; this line adds a checkbox to each table row

Comment: Which tools do you use, for creating a checkbox in those lines? Can you please send us the DOM code, you can access it maybe with `$("th[data-checkbox='true'] input[type=checkbox]")` ?

Comment: That's from Twitter Boostrap and bootstrap-table (http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/)

Answer (score 1):

Finally managed to make it work
Used

```
echo "<th data-field='selected' data-checkbox='true' data-formatter='stateFormatter'></th>";
```

then

```
<script>
  function stateFormatter(value, row, index) {
    if (value == 1) {
      return {
        checked: true
      };
    } else {
      return {
        checked: false
      };
    }
    return value;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("th[data-checkbox='true'] input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked', <?=$selected?'true':'false'?>);
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately that produces no result

Comment: Just so you know, I was able to count the number of checked rows with this line : `var countchecked = $('#' + tableID).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <table>
 <?php
 while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  extract($row);

  $checked_ids = array();
  $checked_ids[] = $id;
  $chk_str = '<input data-index="%s" name="chk" type="checkbox">';
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>";
  printf($chk_str, $id);
  echo "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";

 } 
 ?>
 </table>
 <input type="hidden" id="db_checked" value="<?php echo implode(",",$checked_ids); ?>" />
 <script>
  // need jquery.js
  $(function () {
      var $table = $('#potable'),
      var string = $('#db_checked').val();
      var array = string.split(',');
      for (var ck_id in array) {
       $table.bootstrapTable('check', parseInt(ck_id, 10));
        // check or uncheck
      }
  }
  </script>
```

maybe "data-index" is write at "tr" tags

Comment: I know I can do it this way but this is not what I'm looking for. Thank you anyway ;)

Comment: <input data-index="3" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox">
<script>
 var $table = $('#potable');
$table.bootstrapTable('check', 3);</script>

Comment: modify the function stateFormatter(value, row, index) {
  return { checked: (value == 1) }
}